# Create a Graph from .dot file that contains digraph

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz

I have a .dot file and want to show the contents of the digraph as a visual graph
when i run it keep getting a error. I have looked at many post but have not found the solution that will work.

```
import graphviz as pgv
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib as plt

def load_json(filename):
    import json
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        content = "\n".join(file.readlines())
        return json.loads(content)


distance_graph = load_json('../Main/distanceTables.json')

with open('../Main/distanceTable.dot', 'wt') as file:
    print('Writing: ../Main/distanceTable.dot')
    file.write('digraph {\n')
    for city in distance_graph.keys():
        for adjacent_city in distance_graph[city].keys():
            distance = distance_graph[city][adjacent_city]
            file.write('\t"{}" -> "{}"[label="{}",weight="{}"];\n'.format(city, adjacent_city, distance, distance))
    file.write("}\n")

Gtemp = pgv.Digraph('../Main/distanceTable.dot')
G = nx.Graph(Gtemp)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

error : line 165, in to_networkx_graph
    "Input is not a known data type for conversion.")
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: Input is not a known data type for conversion.

Comment: Any reason when you're using networkx that you're creating a .dot file manually and then reading it back? It'd be simpler to create a networkx graph from the json data and then do what you want with that and if you still want a dot file, use nx.nx_agraph.write_dot on the networkx graph

Comment: @Jon Clements in another post i seen them write it that way so i tried it. I do want to use the json data im not sure how to do that.